# converting string to unicode type in python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying this code:

```
s = "سلام"
'{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))
```

but this error occurs:

> ```
> '{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried `'{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))` but nothing changed.

what should I do?

Comment: Please copy and paste the *text* of a traceback, not a screenshot.

Comment: I copied an pasted it...

Comment: You have a bytestring, *not* unicode. `s` is already encoded in whatever codec your terminal uses.

Comment: yes, if I change it to s = u'سلام' everything solves but it's a variable which I receive from user by a simple input. It's not a static string. how can I put different strings in u'' ?

Comment: What codec is used to send you that variable?

Comment: I receive it by a simple input. I don't precisely know what codec is that. is it ASCII?

Comment: Input in the terminal is encoded with the `sys.stdin.encoding` codec. You can use that to decode to Unicode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using python 2, `s = "سلام"` is a byte string (in whatever encoding your terminal uses, presumably utf8):

```
>>> s = "سلام"
>>> s
'\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85'
```

You cannot `encode` byte strings (as they are already "encoded"). You're looking for unicode ("real") strings, which in python2 must be prefixed with `u`:

```
>>> s = u"سلام"
>>> s
u'\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645'
>>> '{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('utf-8').encode('hex'), 16))
'1101100010110011110110011000010011011000101001111101100110000101'
```

If you're getting a byte string from a function such as `raw_input` then your string is already encoded - just skip the `encode` part:

```
'{:b}'.format(int(s.encode('hex'), 16))
```

or (if you're going to do anything else with it) convert it to unicode:

```
s = s.decode('utf8')
```

This assumes that your input is UTF-8 encoded, if this might not be the case, check `sys.stdin.encoding` first.

i10n stuff is complicated, here are two articles that will help you further:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: it's a variable which I receive from user. It's not a static string. how can I put different strings in u'' ?

Comment: yes, so what should I do? how can I convert it to unicode string?